# unexpected tLabel ')' '=' and else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this syntax error and I don't know what I'm supposed to do and I'm new to Ruby. In the future could someone tell me how I can resolve syntax errors

```
SyntaxError (/Users/admin/Moralyzer/app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
        url: item['url'],
        ^~~~
/Users/admin/Moralyzer/app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
        media_type: item['type']
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/admin/Moralyzer/app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end
      )
      ^
/Users/admin/Moralyzer/app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected else, expecting end
    else
    ^~~~
/Users/admin/Moralyzer/app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:58: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end):
  
app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end
app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected else, expecting end
app/controllers/petition_posts_controller.rb:58: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end
```

The code

```
# POST /petition_posts
  def create
    @petition_posts = PetitionPost.new(petition_posts_params)

    if @petition_posts.save
      for item in media
      @petition_posts.media.create (
        url: item['url'],
        media_type: item['type']
      )
      end
      render json: @petition_posts, status: :created, location: @petition_posts
    else
      render json: @petition_posts.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
@petition_posts.media.create (
    url: item['url'],
    media_type: item['type']
  )
```

To this:

```
@petition_posts.media.create(url:item['url'], media_type:item['type'])
```

All in one line.

**Edit:** I don't mean to edit so much in one minute (I'm kind of new to stackoverflow) but I figured out the issue. It isn't whitespace but where you put the terminating ')' for that function.

So the following are all valid:

```
@petition_posts.media.create(url:item['url'], 
media_type:item['type'])


@petition_posts.media.create(
url:item['url'], 
media_type:item['type'])

@petition_posts.media.create(
url:item['url'], media_type:item['type'])
```

As long as the ')' is attached to the end of your arguments list, you should be good.

Comment: When you say `m(x, y)` then the parentheses are method-calling-parentheses; when you say `m (x, y)`, the parentheses are expression-grouping-parentheses. The latter is an error. If you're going to use parentheses to call a method then no space before the `(`.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby doesn't want white-space between method name and the opening parentheses

```
@petition_posts.media.create (
```

should be

```
@petition_posts.media.create(
```

---

As a bonus point `for` loops are not the Ruby way, use `each` instead

```
media.each do |item|
  @petition_posts.media.create(url: item['url'], media_type: item['type'])
end
```